# How big should XDMA_ENGINE_XFER_MAX_DESC be?

Tags: driver

I'm trying to develop XDMA driver, and I'm confused about one parameter : "XDMA_ENGINE_XFER_MAX_DESC".
How big should it be ? is it related to the hardware or software? and where should i look for it's definition?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: https://github.com/Xilinx/dma_ip_drivers/blob/785995783c78b2cbec6458141c4395e204c5bd9b/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/libxdma.h#L96

Comment: I do see this, I'm confused about how did this value come out?

Comment: That comment doesn't adequately describe what you want to know.  I guess you'd want to google "scatter-gather dma transfer".